# Combobox: disable autocomplete for DropDownList style

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, combobox, copy

OK, so when I have a `combobox` with `DropDownList` style and want just ctrl+c from it it makes 2 things:

- copies the current text to clipboard (that's OK)
- changes current
  selected item since I have some other starts from letter 'c'
  (**THAT'S NOT OK**)

changing `AutoComplete` property doesn't do anything - it doesn't matter whether I set it to `Append`, `Suggest`, `SuggestAppend` or even `None`. Changing the DropDownStyle isn't acceptable for me.

So I'm wondering - if there is any way to:

- handling ctrl+c operation from combobox
- not changing my current selection in combobox

?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If `DropDownStyle` equals `DropDownList`, you can't modify text so you can't copy it.

Comment: I can't modify it - true, but actually i do can copy it! just implemented handling ctrl+c for my combobox

Comment: Are you sure the text gets copied from `DropDownList` ?

Comment: absolutely - i have non-editable combobox but I can copy current text to clipboard

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's one way to "not changing my current selection in combobox" when a Ctrl key is pressed

with `ComboBox1` set to `DropDownList`

```
Dim currentIndex As Integer
    Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyPress(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyPress
        If Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
            currentIndex = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyUp(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyUp
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.ControlKey Then
            ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = currentIndex
        End If
    End Sub
```